# on uwsim, orientation from topic pose and topic imu is different. Why?

Tags: ros, uwsim

[image: Rosanswers logo]

on uwsim, orientation from topic pose and topic imu is different. I set the initial yaw of auv as 0 by modifying yaml file. Quaternion from topic pose is x=0 y=0 z=0 w=1. Quaternion from topic imu is x=0 y=0 z=1 w=0. They are different! why??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227841/on-uwsim,-orientation-from-topic-pose-and-topic-imu-is-different.-why?/) by [ZYS](https://answers.ros.org/users/25674/zys/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2016-02-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

The pose topic (I guess you are talking about /g500/pose) is used to send information between dynamics and simulator. So the dynamics is sending the pose to the visualizer. This pose is referenced from robot initial position (stated in the URDF, or 3D file). Meanwhile IMU topic is a simulated sensor that provides rotation with respect to the simulated world (plus some noise), so the quaternion you obtain from here has an additional rotation which is dependant on the world to initial robot position (offsetr inside simParams in config .xml files).

Short answer is they are different because they mean different things.

---

Originally posted by [Javier Perez](https://answers.ros.org/users/3430/javier-perez/) with karma: 486 on 2016-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0